# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' when using font folder inside res

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, android-studio-2.4

I have updated SDK to Android O developer preview and started a simple demo with single TextView.

When i included `font` inside `res` folder it started showing me

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}
```

**Note :** I am using Android Studio 2.4 Preview 3

If i remove `font` folder from `res`, everything works fine

[image]

Comment: Removing `font` works fine?

Comment: @Wizard yes, if i remove that, it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Is there any build tools released for android O. If yes.. you should update it. because most of the weird issues yielded by build tools.

Comment: I have updated whole SDK, but i don't know what should i write in `buildToolsVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. Beacuase if i write `targetSdkVersion 0`, it shows error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setup worked for me:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0-rc1'
minSdkVersion 'O'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the reference from [Android Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html)

Updating your `gradle` to -

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.0-rc1'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 'O'
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

will going to be fix your all the problems!!

PS, 
**You cannot publish your app with this configuration. The `"O"` version is a provisional API level that is usable only for development and testing during the Android O Developer Preview. You must wait to publish your Android O changes until the final API level is released, and then update your configuration again at that time.**

Comment: yes, thanks a lot for additional information, i was just doing experiments with latest version :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to make Assets Folder inside app and past your font into it 
and you have to register your font in Manifest file

Comment: I think you need to check [this](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html).