# UnsupportedOperationException for MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener

Tags: java, android

I have an activity I am using to that implements a SearchView.

When loading the activity, I am immediately seeing the following error:

```
11-22 20:55:21.013 10008-10008/com.troychuinard.fanpolls E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.troychuinard.fanpolls, PID: 10008
                                                                       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()
                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItemImpl.java:743)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItemCompat.java:464)
                                                                           at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.NewImageActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(NewImageActivity.java:86)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2881)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:328)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:335)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1368)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1648)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:140)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

I do not know if it has to do with the Android API I am using, but essentially I do not know what to change the respective line to in order to remove the error:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchItem.expandActionView();
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back_Press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same 2 days ago and did solve it by using SupportMenuItem instead of MenuItem. Code below shows how I make menu item (in)/visible for another SupportMenuItem for my FilterView as reaction on expanding/collapsing the SearchView.

```
final SupportMenuItem searchItem = (SupportMenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

searchItem.setSupportOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
        filterItem.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }       

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
        filterItem.setVisible(true);
        //adp.cleanMap();
        return true;
    }       
});
```

Here's how I did come to that solution:
There's one hint about a [bug in the 26.0.0-alpha1 release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961535/even-im-using-menuitemcompat-setonactionexpandlistener-my-app-crashes-with-advi). Debugging my code, I detected that my issue might have been related to that as well, as code path "appcompat-v7/26.0.0-alpha1/appcompat-v7-26.0.0-alpha1-sou>
rces.jar!/android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuItemImpl.java" was shown in debugger. Checking that source file revealed the message we are running in:

```
@Override
public MenuItem setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener listener) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
    "This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()");
}
```

I then found the following function in that source as well, which made me give it a try

```
@Override
public SupportMenuItem setSupportOnActionExpandListener(
    MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener listener) {
    mOnActionExpandListener = listener;
    return this;
}
```

Doing it like described works perfectly for me. Any comments on this? Might be a bad idea to use the SupportMenuItem? Actually, my build.gradle contains "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+" - removing that "+" did not change things.

Comment: Much appreciated, we will have to wait for further input on the SupportMenuItem, kind of an odd bug but hopefully your fix is correct! I will let you know if it works and mark as answered.