# Android: Getting "Manifest merger failed" error after updating to a new version of gradle

Tags: android

After accepting to update the project to new version of gradle I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:41 to override.
```

How can I solve this problem?
This is my app's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.bookReader"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    ...
}
```

And this is the project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How do I fix this error while maintaining the changes made by updating the gradle version?

Answer (score 214):

Put this at the end of your app module build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credit to [Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957234/6478047)

Comment: Nice one, this is the solution that worked for me when building my nativescript app

Comment: This did work for me as well, thanks @Vishal. Can you just explain what is happening in here :)

Comment: Please refer below link.                                       https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: Make sure to use the latest version of support library, which at the time of writing this is `details.useVersion '27.0.0'`. Otherwise you won't have the latest support features, like redundant view casting elimination.

Comment: Please add bit description about it. Its working but will it work for updated version and features

Comment: If anyone else had the 'Cannot resolve Symbol DependencyResolveDetails' error, I fixed it by removing 'DependencyResolveDetails' (I read somewhere on StackOverflow about not needing it since its Groovy, so it can dynamically work it out)

Comment: @Vishal sir i have tried but got error again : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.geo.API_KEY@value at AndroidManifest.xml:53:66-112 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY> is provided.?

Comment: For those wondering what this piece of code does. It goes through each dependency, checks what packages each dependency is pulling at making sure that ones that require support libraries pull the correct version

Answer (score 90):

You are using multiple versions of the Android Support Libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25+'
```

Two are `26.0.0-alpha1`, and one is using `25+`.

Pick one concrete version and use it for all three of these. Since your `compileSdkVersion` is not `O`, use `25.3.1` for all three of these libraries, resulting in:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: using `25.3.1` for support libraries or `buildToolsVersion`? for `buildToolsVersion` i get error `Package Unavailable`

Comment: @tux-world: "using 25.3.1 for support libraries or buildToolsVersion?" -- for the support libraries. See my updated answer.

Comment: i test that, but my problem don't resolve, which version must be on `compileSdkVersion` ?

Comment: i get this message `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1`

Comment: @tux-world: Nothing in your `build.gradle` should be referring to `26.0.0-alpha1` anymore. Try cleaning your project (Build > Clean Project) and see if the problem goes away. If not, you are going to need to track down what is pulling in `com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0-alpha1`, such as by running a Gradle dependency report.

Comment: Thanks, i can find which library cause of problem

Comment: That helped ! Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I changed all support library versions to 25.3.1 and worked like a charm:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

You also need to change **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to 25:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: agree, answers above good, but the reason of error is that you set different versions in your gradle file. Just use or 26 or 25 support

Comment: In my case is because of `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 10):

You can find out what library depends on a wrong version of the support library and exclude it like this:

```
compile ('com.stripe:stripe-android:5.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
  }
```

`stripe-android` in my case.

Comment: How do you find out?

Comment: @Zapnologica try to list gradle task dependencies, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Answer (score 6):

I'm not using different versions of libraries and got the same error, it's happened after remove `buildToolsVersion` in AS RC 1, but adding `tools:node="replace"`  did the trick, just add this into your manifest.xml inside `<application ..../>` block:

```
<meta-data 
 tools:node="replace"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: are there any side-effects when doing this? Is it still working for you with the new Android Studio 3?

Answer (score 5):

It happen the same thing to me. See  on Gradle -> Build Gradle -> and make sure  that the compatibility matches in both compile "app compat" and "support design" lines, they should have the same version.

Then to be super sure, that it will launch with no problem, go to File -> Project Structure ->app and check on tab propertie the build Tools version, it should be the same as your support compile line, just in case i put the target SDK version as 25 as well on the tab Flavors.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    *compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'*
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    *compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'*
}
```

Thats what I did and worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

- Update your support library to last version
- Open `Manifest File` , and add it into Manifest File
- `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback"/>`
- And add for recyclerview in  >> `build.gradle Module app` :
- `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'`
- And click : `Sync Now`

Answer (score 3):

I solve that with putting this at the end of my app module build.gradle:

```
    configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.0'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You really made my day.

Answer (score 2):

The answer are accepted but one thing you could also do is to define the libraries from your project structure. What you can do is :

1. Comment all the libraries in which problem is coming
2. Goto your project structure
3. Add libraries from there and it'll sync automatically and the problem goes off.
4. If problem persists try looking from the error log that what library is it demanding after following all the above 3 steps.

What happens is the predefined libraries as off now now I'm taking the **appcompat:26.0.0-alpha1** it uses the older version of the things when you add something new and tries to resolve it with the old stuffs. When you add it from your project structure, it'll add the same thing but with the new stuffs to resolve it. Your problem would be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The error for me was:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:percent:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
```

The solution for me was in my project Gradle file I needed to bump my com.google.gms:google-services version.

I was using version 3.1.1:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1
```

And the error resolved after I bumped it to version 3.2.1:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1
```

I had just upgraded all my libraries to the latest including v27.1.1 of all the support libraries and v15.0.0 of all the Firebase libraries when I saw the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated old android project for the Wear OS. I have got this error message while build the project:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:percent:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.
```

My build.gradle for Wear app contains these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'}
```

**SOLUTION**:

Adding `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` into the dependencies solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the meta data and rebuild project.

Answer (score -4):

you try read link this

Error:Execution failed for task ‘:app:processDevDebugManifest’. Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.0) then usd VERSION 26.0.0

: [https://medium.com/@PongPloyAppDev/error-execution-failed-for-task-app-processdevdebugmanifest-48576be751](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVFVL.jpg)

[image]

Comment: huh? What are you trying to say? how does this help?