# android manifest merger failed, gms play services / firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest, firebaseui

I am trying to add firebase to my app using the firebaseUI. [As the documentations says, I have used the corresponding gms:play-services (11.0.4) with the firebaseUI version (2.2.0)](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)
When I sync the gradle files, I receive following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(25.4.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

This is my gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

//firebase
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.2.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

//firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've made sure that all the versions are up to date and that they are all the same. Can't figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Does adding `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0` resolve the issue?

Comment: No it does not resolve issue. but https://stackoverflow.com/a/45559003/5806017 did

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding:

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43280871/6825464)

The tooltip recommended adding tools:replace="android:value"' to meta-data but this throws another error, so im going with the solution above

Comment: remember to replace "multidex" with the comment of your error log

Comment: but where to add this

Answer (score 26):

I solved it by adding this in `AndroidManifest.xml` within the `<application>` tag at the very bottom:

```
<meta-data 
  tools:node="replace"
  android:name="android.support.VERSION"
  android:value="26.1.0"  // <- The max version you see in the error message. For me it was 26.1.0
/>
```

Then add these two attributes to the `<manifest ... >` tag:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:node="replace"
```

Answer (score 18):

It's happening because **two versions** of support libraries are clashing. On top, you have declared

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

and in dependencies, the version is 26.0.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
```

Just change the support library version to 26.0.1 and it will work fine. I did the same, worked flawlessly in my case.

Answer (score 1):

add this line at the end of app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I forgot to copy the last line, it was already there (updated question)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by hoovering over
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'` and adding the libraries manually that it said was wrong such as

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your manifest

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
```

exactly as shown inside the "application" tag.

Comment: Hi @Pranita unfortunately these type of errors do not have a "one size fits all" fix. That is why their are many answers to try. Try some of the other answers, hopefully you will find the right one for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error has come up because of different libraries added by you.
While adding libraries make sure that all of them are of the same version and work flawlessly with one another.

Comment: the issue is that not all libraries use the same version, even if they are the most up to date compilation. For example, the version of firebase (here 2.2.0) did not use the most up to date 26.0 google library. So if you want to use both libraries regardless, you have to use the workaround explained in the answer(s)

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you use different versions of the same library for implementation in the build.gradle of app module. You can solve this by implementing same versions of a library.

If the problem still persists then add the following code at the end of build.gradle(app module)

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```