# Android sync fails - Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

**The full error is:**

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.1.0.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.jar
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.pom
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.jar
>       https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.pom
>       https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/15.1.0/play-services-auth-15.1.0.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :app

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "alex.ness.edu.xmlandfirebaseandloginto"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

   dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is 15.1.0 out. You should use 15.0.1
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1

There's new versioning of services:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html
Basically you can't assume the same version number for different services.

Comment: I changed: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2' and get this error Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

Comment: you could try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553058/android-manifest-merger-failed-gms-play-services-firebase , also could you accept my answer as it fixes your initial question. thanks

Comment: The information in the above link of stackoverflow unfortunatly did't resolved the problem. This simple thing resolved it:     
 compileSdkVersion 27 and  targetSdkVersion 27

Comment: Does compileSdkVersion 27 and targetSdkVersion 27 work with  com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.1.0? Or it works with 15.0.1 suggested by me?

Comment: 15.0.1 as you have suggested

Comment: cool, so please mark my answer as valid, as 1. it answers your initial question, 2. might help others realizing that google abandoned old style of versioning (I had similar error as yours couple of days earlier) 3. it would be nice of you. thanks!

Comment: Tell me if it is OK? V is green now

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the version of the latter dependency to `15.0.2`. This addresses the issue where version `3.3.0` of the Google Services `Gradle` plugin reports.

or switch to old version -

in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

and in project - `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' // google-services plugin
```

Comment: I changed: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2' and get this error Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.