# android gradle error: libraries must use the exact same version specification.found version 28.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

This is app level dependency.I have been trying to add firebase to my app.but it shows an error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  

    android {  
        compileSdkVersion 28  
        defaultConfig {  
            applicationId "com.example.rachitshah.fireapp"  
            minSdkVersion 15  
            targetSdkVersion 28  
            versionCode 1  
            versionName "1.0"  
            testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false  
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

error in this line

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'  
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'  
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'  
        androidTestImplementation   'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

this is firebase dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Comment: take look to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add firebase dependency in gradle file by adding

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Then there are 2 libraries have been added in your app as well

```
com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
```

Their versions are different from versin 28.0.0 that why the error occurs.

To fix this error, change your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    // Add this line
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
```

Comment: @RachitShah If your problem is solved then you should accepted this as answer.

Comment: How do i that??, i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: In the left side of my answer, there is a tick icon under an arrow icon. You just click on it and done.

Answer (score 0):

check out this post
[android manifest merger failed, gms play services / firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553058/android-manifest-merger-failed-gms-play-services-firebase)

You probably imported a library that does not use the specified version 28. So either remove the specification or make sure they are all on the same version