# Error in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I have an error when i make a new project with Android Studio 3.0
And when ever i try to start Android Studio

Here is the error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:transition:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:26:13-31 value=(26).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

[Here is the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvBNl.png)

Comment: the log say the answer:  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file? It seems like you have conflicting support library versions in it.

Comment: see answer by Vishal worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-update-to-new-version-of-grad