# Native "Push" plugin for Ionic causes errors

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement Push notifications in my ionic app. For this I want to use the native plugin push:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Before installing this plugin I can just start my app on my Android device using:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The app starts up, and no errors occur. But after installing the Cordova/PhoneGap plugin like this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

And this:

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/push
```

I can no longer run the app on my device because the build failes because of a bunch of errors.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.02 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28
:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

This error has a suggestion: adding 'tools:replace="android:value"' to the  eleemet in the AndroidManifest. I did that, after building again I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.171 secs
> Exception while parsing the supplied manifest file D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
[Fatal Error] :13:146: The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "meta-data" is not bound.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Exception while parsing the supplied manifest file D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Another "solution" I found was to add this code piece:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To the **build.gradle** file which fixes the first mentioned error but gives me another error (Push Plugin):

```
BUILD FAILED
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Total time: 12.765 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\FCMService.java:393: error: constructor Builder in class Bu
ilder cannot be applied to given types;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID);
                   ^
  required: Context
  found: Context,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\FCMService.java:403: error: constructor Builder in class Bu
ilder cannot be applied to given types;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID);
                   ^
  required: Context
  found: Context,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I also tried to add this:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.4
```

to the **project.properties** file, but yet another error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bint
ray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.547 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bint
ray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.1.
```

So I also tried to use 11.0.1 (instead of 11.0.4 which are both installed):

[image]

But it gives me this error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.349 secs
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\FCMService.java:393: error: constructor Builder in class Bu
ilder cannot be applied to given types;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID);
                   ^
  required: Context
  found: Context,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\FCMService.java:403: error: constructor Builder in class Bu
ilder cannot be applied to given types;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID);
                   ^
  required: Context
  found: Context,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

At this point I don't really have a clue to fix this, when I remove the plugin like this:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
```

I can just start the app again with no problems or errors.

How can I make this plugin work?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So I created a new Ionic app with a boilerplate like this:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

And I installed the phonegap plugin push like this:

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

And when using this:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The app just starts with no errors, so it is my other project that is causing these issues. I used ionic info on the blank app which shows me this:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\njonkman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v6.11.3
    npm  : 4.6.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

So I did the same for my own app and it was showing some of the fields being outdated (or at least older than what the boilerplate had installed, also cordova) and I started updating the fields like this:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

And

```
npm install -g ionic
```

And

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

But after running it again, I get one of the previous errors:

```
BUILD FAILED in 2s
(node:19208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Data\njonkman\Desktop\kostendeclaratie_mobile - Copy (2)\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(25.4.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:
13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(25.4.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

At this point, wouldn't it be better to just re-create a new project, install all plugins that I need, test if they work and then add my logic/classes to it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

So I have "figured out" what is cousing the problems, I don't know why this happends or how to fix it yet. I am using 2 plugins that work fine alone but both installed, cause errors. These plugins are:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Comment: You could add output of `ionic info` to know version of cordova-android etc..

Comment: If you update your Ionic CLI and create a blank project with only the native push plugin, does it work?

Comment: I have updated my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have managed to solve my problem. This is what I did:

I created a blank Ionic project ( ionic start blank ) to test if the plugin would work in a newly created project. It did. After that I installed all other plugins one by one to see if it still worked. At some point I came across the file-path plugin ( https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/ ). After installing this plugin I got the same errors as mentioned in the OP. After Googling(?) a bit I found this topic:

[android getting Manifest merger failed error after update to new version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-update-to-new-version-of-grad)

One of the solutions was adding this piece of code to the build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I had already tried a similair solution but with a different version number ( 25.3.1 ). The error mentioned 2 versions, I picked the most recent one ( 26.1.0 ) in the solution, but I did not initially.

After trying it out on the blank project I tried it on my existing project. Just to be sure I removed the platform ( ionic cordova rm platform android ) and added it again ( ionic cordova add platform android ). Also note that I added the above piece to the **build.gradle** found in **platforms>android>app** and not in the **build.gradle** found inside  **platforms>android**.

I can now run my project again with no errors.