# The Gradle Sync Failed for my Android Studio Project

Tags: android-studio, synchronization, build.gradle

My android studio project wasn't able to sync with the gradle, I got the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-beta1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-41
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:44 to override.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The same problem?  [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-update-to-new-version-of-grad/44931003)

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure  your dependencies have same version number. Example;

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write this line tools:replace="android:value" into Android Manifest file, if you are face this problem again so please enable androidX after that this issue will resolve.