# I'm trying to add Firebase to my project, got Manifest merger failed error

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest

**I have added**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

to project level gradle file inside buildscript/dependencies.

**I have also added**

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

to app level gradle file inside dependencies

**I have also added** the `google-services.json` file to app folder.

**I have also added** `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the top of app gradle file. (Tutorial says bottom, but I have also fabric's at the top, I don't think it's a problem, I have also tested at the bottom with same result)

**When I try to run the project, I got this error:**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processBetaDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from
> >     [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35      is also present at
> >     [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
> >     value=(26.1.0).       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
> >      element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

**Why could this be?** I have changed nothing else, just added Firebase as official sources described.

I don't want to use `tools:replace` in my manifest, it has led me to many bugs in the past. It feels like a half solution or a quick fix.

**E D I T:**

**Project level gradle file:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App level gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false

            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true

            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Specifies a flavor dimensions. Must have at least one.
    flavorDimensions "myFlavorDimension"

    productFlavors {

        beta {
            applicationId "hu.adamvarhegyi.myproject.beta"
            versionCode 12
            versionName '1.0.94 beta'
        }

        //Release
        standard {
            applicationId "hu.adamvarhegyi.myproject"
            versionCode 12
            versionName '1.0.94'
        }
    }





    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "my_project"
            def SEP = "_"
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = "(v_" + variant.versionCode + ")"
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm')

            def newApkName = project + SEP + buildType + SEP + versionName + SEP + versionCode + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"

            outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
        }
    }


}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
        // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}




dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile project(':gameanalytics')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2')


    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2')
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.2'

    compile('com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1')
    compile('de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0')
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:1.2.3'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    compile(name: 'my_project_engine', ext: 'aar')


}
```

Comment: did you add this line at the bottom of gradle module? 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Can you share build.gradle for project and module level

Comment: @WaleedAsim It's on the top but it doesn't matter, I have also tried at the bottom, see my edit please, I have provided the gradle files

Comment: @adityakamble49 Sure I have added them with an edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Getting "Manifest merger failed" error after updating to a new version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-updating-to-a-new-version)

Answer (score 0):

You are using **different** versions for Android Support Libraries causing this **conflict** in Manifests of different versions of Support libraries

It can be also because any of your dependency using different version of support library as its dependency.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:**26.0.2**] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:**26.1.0**] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

You have to use **same** Android **Support Library** version for all the libraries

You can maintain that manually or add following script to **project** level **build.gradle**

This will **force** all versions of Android Support library to use **same version** So you won't have to maintain it manually

```
allprojects {

    // Force all of the primary support libraries to use the same version.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    details.useVersion versions.supportLibrary
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

Here how you can manage it with more **reliable** way

**dependencies.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    ext.versions = [
            // Basic
            'supportLibrary'       : '26.1.0',
    ]

    allprojects {

        // Force all of the primary support libraries to use the same version.
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                        details.useVersion versions.supportLibrary
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

project level **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    . . .
}

apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
```

module level **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    ...

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLibrary}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${versions.supportLibrary}"

    ...
}
```

This is how you can easily manage all **Android Support library** versions

Comment: Are you using latest gradle plugin available for your android studio? BTW check updated Edit 1 section of post. Let me know if it works