# Manifest merger failed: Attribute application@appComponentFactory

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-manifest

So all good but I'm trying to add this library
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker with this

```
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.0.1'
```

And suddenly when I sync my Graddle it give me this error

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-53:19 to override.
```

And even if I add that suggestion in my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="com.itt.ceatm">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"> // HERE
    <activity...
```

Im not able to get it done because now I get this error

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Here is my full Manifest

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.itt.ceatm"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'

implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.0.1' //NEW LIBRARY

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'}
```

Any advices? I already do a research, trying to do work arround including the block code of configureall and others but no success. Im stuck

Or even another recomendation of a library for DatePicker with material design would be appreciated

EDIT - SOLUTION:
Thanks to all btw
So downgrading the library was ok but then it gave me this error

[Error about different versions support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjAbG.png) (I can't put it directly due to my level, sorry)

Then I did a research and added this new 2 implementations

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0' //THIS
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0' //AND THIS

implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'

implementation "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.4"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'}
```

And then I was able to use the library without errors

Thanks to all again!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842955/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Getting "Manifest merger failed" error after updating to a new version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-updating-to-a-new-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the date-picker has `androidx` as a dependency. downgrading to version `3.6.4` would make it depend on `android.support` again - or upgrade your app to use `androidx`. see [issue 543](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/543).

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker
implementation "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.4"
```

^ this would be the most easy way to fix the conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because the library you are importing is based on androidx which is a major improvement on the support libraries you are using.

Now you three solutions:

1. Use another Date picker library which is based on the previous support versions (Recommended and best way).
2. Change your support libraries to androix. (Recommended but difficult)
3. Add ignore tools (Easy way out)

Here is a link I found:
[Date Picker](https://github.com/Kunzisoft/Android-SwitchDateTimePicker)

```
implementation 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:2.0'
```

Comment: Is a shame I can't accept this answer as well, many thanks tho!

Comment: I did actually, but due to my level it won't show in public :c