# How to solve an error of "Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory"

Tags: android

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My build.gradle Project**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blogapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'


    // firebase core

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    // firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

    // firebase storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'


}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**This is my build.gradle project**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container" />


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**my Activity_home.xml**

my error :

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-25:19 to override.
```

I can't solve even though i already try all things. Even though I add these two lines of code in application tag in manifest.xml.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

but it didn't work, after that show error more.

How can I solve this?

[Manifest merger failed: Attribute application@appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029017/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory)

[Android design support library for API 28 (P) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782435/android-design-support-library-for-api-28-p-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using androidx you don't need

```
   implementation com.google.android.material:material
```

remove this line from gradle.

For androidx

```
 com.google.android.material:material
```

should be used, and if you are using support library

```
  com.android.support:design
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below properties in your gradle.properties file can resolve your problem.

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true