# Could not find manifest-merger.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.0.0) in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3, android-manifest

I have got above error after generating build in ionic3 I have tried a lot of solution but not working tell me, anyone, how to fix above error?
below I have to include //Project-properties file.
I have tried below solution but did not work for me :

1. [Android: Getting "Manifest merger failed" error after updating to a new version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-updating-to-a-new-version)
2. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-run-android-com-android-support-conflicting-v26-alpha1-and-v25-3-1/91826/19

```js
//Project-properties file
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.6
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/app-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/app-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.8=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This solution worked for me

1- In the CordovaLib folder and in the build.gradle file, change the position of the Maven up

```
Repositories {
   maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
   }
   jcenter()
}
```

2- In the general build.gradle file of the project change the position of Maven up and add google()

```
Repositories {
   maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
   }
   google()
   jcenter()
}
```

3- In the build.gradle file of the APP folder change the position of Maven up and add google()

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

4 - Finally, run the "Make Project" that is in the upper corner of Android Studio.
[image: View the image here]

Comment: Had same issue with cordova project build - setting maven repository as the first entry in the \platforms\android\build.gradle file was sufficient for me.

Comment: Resolved issue in my libgdx project as welll using this approach.

Comment: @Danielly Queiroz sorry, but where's the "In the build.gradle file of the APP" ? 
i can find only 2 build-gradle files: one inside "CordovaLib" folder and one inside "android" folder (we're using ionic 1)

Comment: @SimoneCampagna Sorry, but my approach was tested using ionic 3

Comment: @DaniellyQueiroz doesn't matter :) Your solution IMHO is OK but half solution in our build scenario: but i repeat is correct!
So many thanks :)

Comment: This worked for me in an Appache/Cordova project. There were slight differences but I could see what to do.

Comment: This also worked for me , but you have to explain how did you come up with this ? I compared the files you listed between two different projects and one had the same thing you wrote and the other had to be fixed. Why did this happen ? why are they different ? However thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I did the following :

`ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic build android`

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! 
Had the same issue with cordova project build--setting maven repository as the first entry in both \platforms\android\build.gradle and \platforms\build.gradle files.

Comment: for me, it was: platforms/android/build.gradle; platforms/android/app/build.gradle; platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` in Top-level build file to the android studio itself version and it worked.

you can find the current studio version in `Help - About`.