# Android Studio Flagging my widget as incompatible types

Tags: android, android-studio

I have multiple widgets that you would normally initialize like this,

```
 public EditText editTextTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_job);

    editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTxtTitle);
}
```

but then it gives me this error[image]

However when I go to my xml it shows that it is in fact an editText.

This all happened when I changed my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.worktide.worktide"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            // Skip multidex because it follows a different versioning pattern.
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> EDIT

I am pretty sure my xml has nothing to do with this problem that I get after removing the multidexing. [image]

Comment: Please post your XML too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multidexing in a wrong way. Refer to the following reference.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Also, you should migrate to [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) for getting new features and upgrades on existing support library.

Remove the following code since it is trying to use old versions of support library.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            // Skip multidex because it follows a different versioning pattern.
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The build.gradle file should be after removing above code block

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.worktide.worktide"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
}
```

If problem exists even after syncing gradle file. You might need to invalidate caches and restart from `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

**Update**

After fixing multidexing related code following error was observed

[image: Merger Manifest Failed]

It is caused by the mixing of androidx library `com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0` on non-androidx project. The project should be migrated to andoridx to use androidx libraries.

**Note:** Androidx project can use older support version libraries.

Comment: To add on, if the OP does not delete the code, then he/she must use casting.

Comment: Since the type of `editTextTitle` is already specified, casting is not necessary when calling `findViewById()` starting with API level 26.

Comment: But as you can see, if the OP does not delete the code, the OP must do so because of his/her minSdkVersion (21).

Comment: Hi if I remove this it actually gives me this error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280871/android-getting-manifest-merger-failed-error-after-updating-to-a-new-version

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException minSdkVersion 21 will not cause any problem since the change in `findViewById` is backward compatible too.

Comment: Ah, fair. Thank you

Comment: @Kristofer use 28.0.0 for support version libs now and follow the multidexing as mentioned in android developer doc. Do gradle sync properly, you won't be getting any problem.

Comment: @SagarChapagain but I already have 28.0.0 in my code as you can see on the build.gradle, so what should I change?

Comment: @Kristofer I had updated the answer. If problem still occurs, edit your question and include the content of layout file `activity_create_job `.

Comment: @Kristofer you are getting the `merger manifest failed` because one of the library used `com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0` uses androidx component which differs from `com.android.support` variants used in your project. So you are getting that problem. I suggest you to migrate to androidx via `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`. Migration process is very stable and you won't get any issues.

Comment: @Kristofer I had updated the answer again to include your merger manifest failed error.