# Resolve Manifest Merger Failed error - tools:replace

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

A conflict on Android Support library versions 25.3.1 and 26.0.0-alpha1 is causing a manifest merger failed error when performing a Gradle sync.

**How can we use a  tag with tools:replace property as Android Studio / gradle suggests to fix this error?**

(i.e. what is the exact syntax within AndroidManifest.xml to force usage of support:design:25.3.1 instead of 26.0.0-alpha1 which an included library is using)

This is the error Gradle is producing:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
    is also present at [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.
```

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Support Repo 46.0.0 with Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949974/android-support-repo-46-0-0-with-android-studio-2-3)

Answer (score 9):

Add the following to your build.gradle "app level", just after you dependencies:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
def requested = details.requested
if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
details.useVersion '25.3.1'
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have that solution and it works, but I'm trying to learn how to correct this problem within AndroidManifest.

Comment: @Baker i think i am having the same problem, i import [reCaptcha] (https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA) and i have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` on dependence. my won't complie with `Error:
 Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.`

Answer (score 0):

In your **`app:gradle`** file, replace

```
'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

with

```
'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```