# Ionic diagnostic plugin error when building in Phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am trying to ask the user permission before accessing their camera. I use the ionic diagnostic plugin for this. The app builds fine on Phonegap build before adding the diagnostic plugin. After adding plugin I get the following error through Phonegap build:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
  >   is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
  >   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override

I installed the plugin using the following:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/diagnostic
```

And in my config.xml I have the following:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />

<plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^3.6.5"/>
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

I think that error is not related to the diagnostic plugin. A few days ago I updated my support repository and the same error started to show up on my end. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949974/android-support-repo-46-0-0-with-android-studio-2-3) the issue is because:

> Some libraries depend on version "X or newer" of Android support
>   libraries so Gradle dependency resolution grabs whatever is the newest
>   available ignoring you actually have a precise version specified in
>   your dependencies block.
>
> This is not what you want. You want all support libraries with same
>   version and major version has to match compile SDK version.

So in order to solve it, go to the `build.gradle` file, located in `projectName/platforms/android/build.gradle` and add the following at the end of the file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace the version with whatever it is you're using, but given the error you posted, `25.3.1` seems like the correct version to be used.

Comment: I don't have a build.gradle file in my ionic project. Is there an equivalent file that I can add this code to?

Comment: Have you checked in the `/platforms/android/` folder?

Comment: I added the the android platform and then I could see `/platforms/android/build.gradle`. I added the code to the end but still produces the same error.

Comment: Really? So you're still getting that error when building the app?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by [@sebaferreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915438/sebaferreras), I've created a plugin which wraps the Gradle config and allows it to be pulled into a Cordova project dynamically (which really helps if you use CI for your builds): [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release).

Basically, just add it to your project and it will force any specified support library versions to the latest major release (currently `v25`):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release
```

Comment: Added the plugin. But still get the same error unfortunately. I don't seem to see the gradle-release plugin in the config.xml file after adding. Is this expected?

Comment: Building locally or Phonegap Build?

Comment: `I don't seem to see the gradle-release plugin in the config.xml file after adding. Is this expected?` Depends on your `cordova` version: v7 saves it automatically; <v7, you need to use `--save`. But it's just like any other plugin.

Comment: I am using Phonegap Build. And Cordova 6.3.1. I was under the impression that Phonegap Build will not see the plugin if it is not listed in the `config.xml` file. And because the build fails, I can't tell for sure if the `gradle-release` plugin is picked up by Phonegap. Certainly not listed in the log.

Comment: Also I added the diagnostic plugin to a brand new project, and it built fine on Phonegap Build. Could the diagnostic plugin be clashing with another plugin that I have in my actual project?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem - they are specifying different versions of the Android Support libraries. Hence the need for the `gradle-release` plugin.

Comment: That's amazing @DaveAlden, thanks a lot for this plugin (and for all your plugins!) :)

Comment: Awesome! If only it hadn't taken me so long to find this.  Thanks Dave & @sebaferreras

Comment: @GabeO'Leary glad to hear that it helped :)