# Android Manifest merger error

Tags: android

I keep on getting Manifest merger error. The Gradle dependency is shown in the [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imAT9.png).

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.
```

Comment: You are using multiple different versions of the Android Support Library artifacts. If you edit your question and post the `dependencies` closure from `app/build.gradle`, perhaps we can give you more specific advice.

Comment: You can try to exclude support libs from customtabs dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either you find the library that is using a different support library version or use a resolution strategy and add this at the end of your app module build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information please check:  [Android Support Repo 46.0.0 with Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949974/android-support-repo-46-0-0-with-android-studio-2-3)