# What support library version should we use with targetSDK 28?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-9.0-pie

I was going through this [article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-p-beta-3-is-now-available.html) , it says to `update your project's compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to API 28` . So I did but the support library gave error like support library should not use different version than compileSdk version

[image]

I tried updating it to 28.0.0 but its not working and says

`Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`

I know it will still work with `27.1.1` but what is the correct version to use which won't give red underline ?

**EDIT**

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'   

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.eightfolds.safety"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

ext.support_version = '28.0.0'
ext.room_version = "1.1.1"
ext.lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3'

    //Room (remove apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'  at top)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'   // for Kotlin
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.pddstudio:encrypted-preferences:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.6'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'


}

//below part of code credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957234/6478047    

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "$support_version"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please share your **`build.gradle`** file with question

Comment: @NileshRathod done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `Revision 28.0.0 Alpha 1` for android p
but it is a preview version

Visit https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages for latest support-libraries

Answer (score 7):

I know this has already been answered but I needed to update mine today as well and neither of the links from the answers above actually told me what to put. So I had to use the following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01'
```

I hope this helps someone else looking for what to put there.