# Crash with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to compile and run a demo app that was written for an old Android version.

I have updated all the files to use the new androidx libraries. That included the gradle.build the manifest and layout files.
It compiles properly but crashes on the main activity on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

From looking at the stack trace I can deduce that its related to the layout.xml file as the app crash when it set for the first time.
But I could not find any problem with the layout file after migrating the FloatingActionButton from the old to the new deisgn librarey.

Any ideas?

Stack:

```
I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2423)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:750)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:529)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.example.android.emojify.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:75)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
I/zygote:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.emojify"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.emojify.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/emojify_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin"
        android:text="@string/emojify_me"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/emojify_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clear"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margins"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margins"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margins"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_save"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margins"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margins"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margins"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in your `gradle.properties` file: add

`android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: also for `espresso`  https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup

Comment: for more androidx https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849025/4649110

Comment: @Basi - I forgot to mention that I already used these parameters in gradle.properties and read the article about migrating to AndroidX but didn't find anything that I did not do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after update dependency into build.grade file to androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02 problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your test implementation is support one yet, change for

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Comment: You are right that I missed this one but its not related to the error. It is still crashing.

Comment: So try to redo the layout. Some components change imports as ConstraintsLayouts. Let Android Studio autocomplete them and you will se the change. You can copy/paste margins and those common things but put again the layouts

Answer (score 0):

You are using material component

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

try to use material theme in you app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">` but I get the crash.

Comment: can you comment with crash report

Comment: basically the same call stack as the opening question

Comment: Do you have permission to upload it to GitHub, I can run it and debug it?

Comment: This will be one of the apps: https://github.com/DIYGPSTracker/DIYGPSManager (+ the companion app the DIYGPSTracker). I wouldn't spend time on it since I'm almost certain that there are 3 possible solutions non of which I want to apply for different reasons 1. `@RequiresApi(28)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954286/292502 2. Fiddling with dex https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161064/292502 3. Or fiddling with the lib with AspectJ https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664338/292502