# How to Solve Mix version Error in Build.gradle android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

As I am using latest version of Android Studio and getting warning / error in build.gradle file

All com.android.support libraries must use same exact version . Found version 28.0.0 and 26.1.0 . animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and support-media-compat:26.1.0

Tried all answers an Options that already are on Stack Overflow but nothing worked .

Can Somebody help , What is the Problem .

Here is Android Studio SS 
[image]

Comment: I guess that other library is using lower version and that is why you have this warning, this is not causing compile error

Comment: @MaksimNovikov no not causing an error but it may cause to crash the app , how can i solve this?

Comment: It should not cause crash.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix it

1) Hover your mouse on top of the error for some time and it will show you what libraries have mixed versions , just add those libraries in your project .

In your case add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

It may show other libraries after adding this . Add those libaries too .  All support library packages can be found over [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

2) Add this at the end of app level build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "28.0.0"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Credit to [Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957234/6478047)

Comment: Thanks @Redman but it resolve the error but now it give error Saying that 

can not resolve symbol DependencyResolveDetails .

Comment: Clean project, delete build,.gradle,.idea folders (donot rebuild project ) file->invalidate cache/restart . It rebuild when studio opens  and should fix issue

Comment: Where should i find those folders ? in my Project folder? @Reman

Comment: yes in your project there will be `.gradle` and `.idea` folders and inside app folder there will be `build` all of these are safe to delete

Comment: Thanks @Redman Done that but still same error can not resolve symbol DependencyResolveDetails

Comment: is your project running fine ?

Comment: Yes compile and Runs fine but actually i am trying to draw paths between Current Location and destination , haven't done that yet . will this be a problem after project is completed ? @Redman

Comment: No , I have it in more than 5 projects now . Never had an issue

Comment: So 'DependencyResolveDetails ' giving an error or working fine in ur projects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187644/discussion-between-redman-and-rashid-kalhoro).

Answer (score 1):

There are **some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries**, that are incompatible, or can **lead to bugs**. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the **Android support libraries that is not the latest version** (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).
So, if you want to remove this warning because it will not give compile time error then write the given line above this error line:-

//noinspection GradleCompatible

If you don't want to face any problem in future then i suggest to use those tools and libraries which have same version as support libraries

Comment: yes i already tried this and it wiorked but is it cause app crash maybe in future?

Comment: then i suggest to use those tools and libraries which have same version as support libraries