# I'm stuck when i try to use android-image-cropper:2.8.+

Tags: android, dependencies, android-studio-3.0

When i add to this line `implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'` in my dependency 
it cause error

*** my error ***

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-25:19 to override.
```

And

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:`28.0.0'

this line become red line

I think the problem is reason of version

How can I avoid that clash?

I already try to change version and add code in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<usespermissionandroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but it didn't work

**This is my manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blogapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.PostActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.HomeActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is my dependency**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blogapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }



dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.4"

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I hope use this imageCropper no trouble in my dependency
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled this issue by importing this library as module and replacing dependencies from

```
dependencies {
api "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidXLibraryVersion"
implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:$androidXLibraryVersion"
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"
}
```

And updating imports in all files of library

Answer (score 6):

The library has moved to a new one (old one not maintained)

https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Read [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/806)

Comment: Thanks. Finally the new library works perfect with no gradle issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use version `2.7.0`

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

version 2.8.0 uses androidx support libraries , so use it only if you use androidx support libraries in your project

> **Change log**
>
> 2.8.0
>
> 1. Fix crash on Android O (thx @juliooa)
> 2. Update to support library to AndroidX (thx @mradzinski)
> 3. Handle failure when selecting non image file (thx @uncledoc)
> 4. More translations (thx @jkwiecien, @david-serrano)

**EDIT :**

Add this at the end of app level `build.gradle` file

```
configurations.all {
 resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {  details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "28.0.0"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Credit to [Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957234/6478047)

Comment: I was try do this before but after i change version 2.7 but when i change that 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
show red line and show me message like this
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1 more... (Ctrl+F1)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use below

```
implementation com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+
```

Add two lines in `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: But after i add that two lines one of my implement occured error  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivit 
Is that incompatible?

Comment: yes, after you need to use AppCompatActivit from androidx . it means you need to change your import.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about case but after facing same issue it was because i did not add

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

This line in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

change version don't use + if you use android studio bumblebee, go to `setting.gradle`, and add `jcenter()` :

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```