# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;

Tags: android, gradle

I have some problem with build.Gradle

I am getting the following error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.evatro.workforce.android.eti, PID: 16965
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
            at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator.resetAnimation(DefaultItemAnimator.java:514)
            at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator.animateMove(DefaultItemAnimator.java:254)
            at android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.animateDisappearance(SimpleItemAnimator.java:90)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.animateDisappearance(RecyclerView.java:3252)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$700(RecyclerView.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.processDisappeared(RecyclerView.java:431)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ViewInfoStore.process(ViewInfoStore.java:236)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3098)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2917)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1767)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1009)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:719)
            at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:984)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:732)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1172)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6401)
```

Below is the build.gradle file

```
   compileSdkVersion 24


    defaultConfig {

        compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1254'
        applicationId "....."
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 56

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.49.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.49.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.+'
    compile 'com.iangclifton.android:floatlabel:1.0.4'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:1.0.8.Final'

    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"

    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.5.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this code in your build.gradle file in the app folder

**please add below code at the end of file .**

```
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ref with this 
[Android Support Repo 46.0.0 with Android Studio 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949974/android-support-repo-46-0-0-with-android-studio-2-3/42957234#42957234)

answer

I hope this will help you, happy coding

Comment: it says Cannot resolve symbol 'DependencyResolveDetails' and I am addin end of file right? like that;  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: remove "DependencyResolveDetails" and then try .
Please check below code

 configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: i have edited answer please add above code at the end of the app module build.gradle file .